# explaination double asterisk returned value from array (in C)

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

I have an array:

```
char *p[2][3] = {"abc","defg","gi","jklmno","pqrstuvw","xyz"};
```

and when i print the following syntax the compiler print strange values, and i didn't understand why:

```
printf("%c", **p); // Print 'j'
printf("%c", *p[1]); // Print 'v'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check the data types.

Comment: Not sure what you want to print, but `**p` is of type `char*`, so if your intention was printing the first character of the very first string, then `***p` is the one. Similarly in the second statement, if your intention was to print the fist character from the second row of strings, then `**p[1]` will be what you want.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  For instance, the compiler will tell you that the initializer is missing some braces '{' and '}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization of the array is incorrect. Since you're trying to create a 2 dimensional array, some braces are missing:

```
char *p[2][3] = {{"abc","defg","gi"},{"jklmno","pqrstuvw","xyz"}};
```

The specifier s has to be used to print an array:

```
printf("%s", **p); //abc
printf("%s", *p[1]); //jklmno
```

You should not use the dereference operator directly. Always use the array subscript operator:

```
printf("%s", p[0][0]); //abc
printf("%s", p[1][0]); //jklmno
```

Comment: you don't need the braces it actually works with  char *p[2][3] = {"abc","defg","gi","jklmno","pqrstuvw","xyz"};

Comment: @IamNguele Not in C. You must be relying on compiler extensions.

Comment: however the environment is not precised and the positioning in the memory is the same

Comment: @IamNguele Assuming you're talking about the topic of this post. It is defined by tags. The relevant tag on this question is `c`. No tag specifies extensions. Of course there is nothing wrong with using them, but it should be pointed out that they are used and they are not specified by the  C standard.

Comment: Run it with your compiler and see

Answer (score -1):

Basically what you did creates a two dimensional array of strings which gives you:

```
*p[0] = {"abc","defg","gi"};
*p[1] = {"jklmno","pqrstuvw","xyz"};
```

**p will point at the address of the first word in *p[0] which is "abc", except that so when you do call printf("%c", **p) it will actually try to display the memory address of "abc" as a character hence the random result. Per exemple running your code I get @ and L. However if you do this instead:

```
printf("%d\n", **p);
printf("%d\n", *p[1]);
```

The printf calls will display the pointers values which are the addresses of "abc" and "jklmno". Now if you do this:

```
printf("%s\n", **p);
printf("%s\n", *p[1]);
```

You will see "abc" and "jklmno" displayed as printf will understand that it is supposed to read a string from the memory addresses pointed at by **p and *p[1]. Also I forgot to mention that **p is the same as *p[0]. If you want to display the first character of the first string from the first array you should call:

```
printf("%c\n", ***p); // ***p is the same as p[0][0][0]
```

Hope it helps.